# Traefik is not creating certs for subdomains using the docker backend

Tags: docker, ssl, lets-encrypt, traefik

When using the docker backend for traefik, lets encrypt certs are only generated for the main domain but not for any subdomains. I have followed this guide: [Docker and Lets Encrypt](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/docker-and-lets-encrypt/). The main domain has certs from lets encrypt. When running a docker container with labels no certificate is generated.

Docker version = 17.10, Traefik version = traefik:1.5

Here is my traefik.toml configuration:

```
 defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[web]
address = ":8080"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[acme]
email = "email@example.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
  [acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"
OnHostRule = true

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "example.com"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false
```

and here are the tags I am using:

```
  "traefik.backend": "test",
  "traefik.docker.network": "proxy",
  "traefik.enable": "true",
  "traefik.frontend.rule": "Host:test.example.com",
  "traefik.port": "8000"
```

The certificate on example.com is:

```
Issued to: example.com
Issued by: Lets Encrypt Authority X3
```

and the certificate on test.example.com is:

```
Issued to: TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT
Issued by: TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Lets-encrypt Issued to: example.com only. Does traefik run cert-bot to generate certs?

Answer (score 2):

This is the only way I got it to work: by specifying the acme.domains like this

```
[docker]
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  watch = true
  exposedbydefault = false

[entrypoints.traefik]
  address=":8080"

[api]
  dashboard = true
  entryPoint = "traefik"

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[acme]
email = "email@example.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
acmeLogging = true
  [acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"

  [[acme.domains]]
    main = "domain1.com"
    sans = ["www.domain1.com","other.domain1.com"]
  [[acme.domains]]
    main = "domain2.com"
    sans = ["www.domain2.com","other.domain2.com"]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without knowing the subdomains in advance?

Comment: let's encrypt support [wildcards cert](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/acme-v2-production-environment-wildcards/55578) now, and traefik config [here](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/5317)